# Angular on Azure Static Web App bugs out on refresh

Tags: angular, azure, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I've had an Angular application deployed to Azure Static Web Apps via Github Actions, with a staticwebapp.config.json configured as follows:

```
"trailingSlash": "auto",
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["*.{css,scss,js,png,gif,ico,jpg,svg}"]
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".scss": "text/x-scss",
    ".html": "text/html",
    ".svg": "image/svg+xml"
  }
```

I've even tested it out locally with the Azure Static Web Apps emulator, and everything seems to work with the stated settings. However, when I deploy the application to an Azure Static Web App, the application will start to bug out on refresh, making the url of the front page of the application, the login page, look like this

***url appends another route on refresh***

[image]

it also makes the whole app unusable after this, throwing this error:

***errors thrown by the application***

[image]

When I close the browser window and open it again, everything works, except for when getting the svg assets from the application, where it uses whatever url the application is currently on to get the asset files.
For example: it's calling https://myapp.com/login/assets/myicon.svg instead of https://myapp.com/assets/myicon.svg

May I know what I'm doing wrong here? Sources online all point the issue to the staticwebapp.config.json but I've already had it configured the same as what the documentations are suggesting. I apologize if this is a noob question, I'm quite new to Azure Static Web Apps and Github actions

I tried tweaking the staticwebapp.config.json, adding the 'routes' property to no avail.
I tried to configure the Github actions yaml file to run 'npm run build' on every deployment (not sure if that will help), but I don't see any differences. Currently I'm using the hash location strategy to temporarily fix the issue

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub repo.

Comment: @Harshitha May I have your username so I can add you to the repository? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sue..HarshithaVeeramalla

Comment: Try to remove `/` before index.html in `rewrite` and check once.

Comment: I've tried that already, doesn't work :(